# With WSS, is it possible to customize the Admin?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, interface, wss, administration

I'm thinking of implementing WSS, but I want complete control over the Admin interface, as far as look-and-feel and navigation.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could certainly write [features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460318.aspx) involving [custom actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms473643.aspx) and [application pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb418732.aspx) to do this.

If you don't have much experience with SharePoint development but know ASP.NET, I recommend reading [Inside Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=9692) by Ted Pattison and Daniel Larson. It's well written and has some great information on how to plug into the SharePoint user interface and add this type of functionality.

Answer (score 2):

What the others said.. but what are you trying to achieve? 
The admin pages I usually keep intact for most projects. I just bolt-on features that I need. 
Also, admin interface is a wide term. Is modifying a view an admin task? You could be looking at a lot of work.. to what end?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about direct customization, but it's all available through an API and possibly through web services, so you should be able to write your own, either as part of the WSS site or separately.

Answer (score 0):

In WSS 3.0 (and MOSS 2007) the look and feel is controlled through Master Pages.  Locate the Master Pages and Themes associated with the Admin site and change it the way you want.

If you need to change the actual way it works be careful and make sure you backup everything before you make any changes.

There are a number of preset templates available from [Microsoft Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/sharepoint/bb407286.aspx) that might help you out.  There is also an article over at [ASP Alliance](http://aspalliance.com/1376_Customizing_WSS_30_with_Master_Pages.4) that gives some information as to where the Admin Master Pages are located. Also there is a good blog entry over on [MSDN by Joel Oleson](http://blogs.msdn.com/joelo/archive/2007/04/12/master-page-and-themes-on-wss-sites-in-moss.aspx) that describes modifying Master Pages and Themes in WSS and MOSS.

Answer (score 0):

2 options:

- create a custom theme, but then you're still stuck to the default SP HTML
- copy application.master into a new file and modify the html / css, the set that as the SP admin master